.NET 8 Blazor web app - single sign-on with Windows credentials
I want to migrate my .NET 7 Blazor Server solution to .NET 8 Blazor web app template.
When I first time come to the page, everything is ok, when I refresh the page I get an error:

Access to host localhost is denied.
You do not have user rights to view this page.
HTTP 403 ERROR

Here is my sample project: https://easyupload.io/5oejk7
If anyone has already faced something like that any help is more than welcome.
What I realized is that CustomServerAuthenticationStateProvider is not triggered on page refresh. I was checking already everywhere and checking a lot of different approaches but none of them work, so I can't figure out what I need to do to solve that.

You can try adding authorization attributes to the  component to ensure that only users with a specific role can access the content it contains. For example: (<AuthorizeView Roles="Admin">), this can be suitable for scenarios where different content is dynamically displayed based on the current user's role, so that the content can be displayed based on the current user's role. The following are related links for your referencehttps://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-8.0#role-based-and-policy-based-authorization

AuthorizeView does not help with solving my issue at all.
Authentication otherwise works ok.
Reload issue is what is bothering me.

I managed to find a proper solution for the issue....
If anyone find it usefull in the end...
https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/5362704/Blazor-windows-authentication-with-custom-claims
